# Removing array square brackets from JSON encode | PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PHP script that select all names according to criteria, I would like the json data to be formatted as:

```
{"person":"Jake"}
```

Currently it is formatted like:

```
[{"person","Jake"}]


  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `person`
        FROM `Table1`
        WHERE (`name` = :name
        AND
        (`job` = "collection")
        group by `customer` ');

  $stmt->execute([
      'name' => $_POST['name']
      ]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($row);
```

What can be done different to format the output without the square brackets

Comment: `fetchAll()` will return an array of all row, so if you want the first row only use  `echo json_encode($row[0]);` or you can fetch only one row using `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` then you can `echo json_encode($row);`

Comment: How can you get `[{"person","Jake"}]`, it should be `[{"person":"Jake"}]`.

Comment: I'm just curious about why your need data in that format?

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo, it is currently [{"person":"Jake"}]

Answer (score 0):

`{"person","Jake"}`

This data you want is an object. And you are fetching an array with this

`$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

If you want to get that single output then use `$row = $stmt->fetch()` instead.

Or you can still get that result by looping the result. Or call the first index `echo json_encode($row[0]);`

Comment: Something to add: using `fetch()` without stating fetching style will get both indexed and assoc style, so the result will look something like this: `{"0": "Jake", "name": "Jack"}`

Comment: @catcon unless you set it as a default fetch mode